# react-native-phone-input white content on iphone

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-phone-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-input) to allow my users to add a phone number.

The problem is that on some iOS version, I do not really why the text is white.
On my iPhone I have no issues but one of my users which is a `iPhone xs max` everything is white

[image]

This library is good but not really maintained

I use it like that

```
<PhoneInput
    style={styles.input}
    ref={ref => { this.phone = ref }}
    initialCountry={this.state.region}
    value={this.props.number}
    allowZeroAfterCountryCode={false}
/>
```

And the style

```
input: {
        padding: 5,
        borderRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#000',
        marginBottom: 10,
        color: '#000'
    }
```

I added a black color to be sure but I still have the issue on some devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because of the `darkMode` of the iOS. In case of the dark mode in iOS, the text input's color get white if no any color is supplied in the style of the text input. The `style` which you are using is not set to the text input. Try passing the black color in `textProps` prop like:

```
<PhoneInput
    textProps={{
        style: {
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }}
    ref={ref => { this.phone = ref }}
    initialCountry={this.state.region}
    value={this.props.number}
    allowZeroAfterCountryCode={false}
/>
```

If you want to disable dark mode's effect on your entire app, you can add `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to the `Info.plist` file in iOS like:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
```